# What is this component in the image?

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to know what is the black circular component stacked in front of the switch and adjacent to the large capacitor in this circuit board.

I am not talking  about the transistor with the heat sink. I am talking about the circular black component.

This thing has 4 pins in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Bridge rectifier. Pins should be labelled ~ ~ + -.

Comment: close up photo of that component showing the labelling  is probably necessary.

Comment: http://www.mccsemi.com/PDF/BridgeRectifiers.pdf

Comment: 400V PIV 1.5A bridge rectifier.

Comment: And by the way it's not "a transistor with heat sink", but a 7805 linear voltage regulator (5V).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This element is a bridge rectifier. The two oposite pins are AC input (designated with ~ ) and the other two are DC output (designated with + and - ).

Answer (score 0):

That is rectifier of 4M ohm. + and minus labels are DC output. ~ labeled pins are AC input. Keep + on top and - at bottom then right side ~ is Phase and left side is Neutral.